# How to remove a resource (Google Docs document) from the root collection (folder)

Tags: python, gdata, google-docs-api, gdata-api

I am using the python gdata library to copy and move a google Docs file in a specific folder. I am using the MoveResource method from DocsClient, the file appears in the desired folder, but also stays in the root folder.

I cannot figure out how to remove it from the root folder?!

```
import gdata.docs.service
import gdata.docs.client
import gdata.docs.data

doc_service = gdata.docs.client.DocsClient() 
doc_service.ClientLogin('myId', 'myPassword', 'myAppName')

# this is my source document
doc = doc_service.GetResourceById('ABC123')

# extracting the folder of my source document to move the copy in the same folder
for parent in doc.InCollections(): 
    if parent.title == 'myFilter':
        destination_folder_id = parent.href.split('%3A')[1]
        destination_folder = doc_service.GetResourceById(destination_folder_id)

# making a copy of my source
newdoc = doc_service.CopyResource(doc, 'Test Python')

# moving my copy to the same folder as my source
# but the copy also stays in the root folder!
moveddoc = doc_service.MoveResource( newdoc, destination_folder )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the Google Docs file from the root collection using this code:

```
doc_service.Delete('https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/folder%3Aroot/contents/' + doc.resource_id.text, force=True)
```